# linux-generic disco-proposed will upgrade thunderbird?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, updates

I included disco-proposed to my source. It is pinned with priority 200.

```
root@Guilmon:~# apt-cache policy | grep prop
 200 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=19.04,o=Ubuntu,a=disco-proposed,n=disco,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
 200 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=19.04,o=Ubuntu,a=disco-proposed,n=disco,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
 200 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-proposed/main amd64 Packages
     release v=19.04,o=Ubuntu,a=disco-proposed,n=disco,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
root@Guilmon:~#
```

Try to upgrade linux-generic from there.

```
root@Guilmon:~# LANG=C
root@Guilmon:~# apt upgrade -t disco-proposed linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-38 linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apt apt-utils dpkg dpkg-dev gir1.2-nm-1.0 libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libdpkg-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev-bin libnm-dev libnm0 libsnapd-glib1 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic login
  network-manager passwd python3-apport python3-problem-report rsyslog thunderbird thunderbird-locale-de
30 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 122 MB of archives.
After this operation, 337 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

another try,

```
root@Guilmon:~# apt --dry-run install --reinstall linux-generic=5.0.0.38.40
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 5.0.0.38.40) but 5.0.0.37.39 is to be installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.0.0.38.40) but 5.0.0.37.39 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@Guilmon:~#
```

I think this is related due my apt-pining.

and another one

```
root@Guilmon:~# apt --dry-run  -t disco-proposed install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-38 linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-5.0.0 | linux-source-5.0.0 linux-tools
Recommended packages:
  thermald
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-38 linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Inst linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-generic [5.0.0.37.39] (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-generic [5.0.0.37.39] (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-5.0.0-38 (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [all]) []
Inst linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-generic [5.0.0.37.39] (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-generic (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-image-generic (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-5.0.0-38 (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [all])
Conf linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic (5.0.0-38.41 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-generic (5.0.0.38.40 Ubuntu:19.04/disco-proposed [amd64])
root@Guilmon:~#
```

27 not upgraded.

```
root@Guilmon:~# sudo apt update 
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                     
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97,5 kB]   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97,5 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88,8 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-proposed InRelease [255 kB]
Fetched 539 kB in 1s (552 kB/s)                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@Guilmon:~#
```

Okay, I know it is proposed and normally I can handle it. But I do not see the connection between linux-image and thunderbird and other packages.

Note this is a fresh install ubuntu disco. No ppa's. No snaps/flatpacks.

thanks for reading and Merry Christmas

Comment: There is no connection between `linux-generic` and `thunderbird` at all. `linux-image` is related to kernel only.

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Pilot6 maybe for you.  if the kernel is not working, I can boot an other, and remove him. Are other programs not working I have to downgrade then. because all of them come from proposed.

Comment: Why don't you ask something like "How do I upgrade Thunderbird?"

Comment: I only want to upgrade the kernel not thunderbird and the other packages. I don't  understand why the other one also will be upgraded besides the kernel packages  (all from proposed)

Comment: @karel sadly not.  but I get it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sometimes are a sleepyhead. I have to tell apt which version I want.

```
root@Guilmon:~# apt install linux-generic=5.0.0.38.40 linux-image-generic=5.0.0.38.40 linux-headers-generic=5.0.0.38.40
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-38 linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-5.0.0 | linux-source-5.0.0 linux-tools
Recommended packages:
  thermald
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-38 linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic linux-image-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-38-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/67,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 336 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```